# Django ORM queryset to match a value that contains a suffix with the value on the database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to match strings with unexpected additional suffix and then select the database in the string.

**Example Model**:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='abcdef', unique=True)
```

**Code:**

```
string = 'abcdef'
unexpected_suffix = '_d'  # This is random and can be '_e', 'eeee', '321'

_string = '{0}{1}'.format(string, unexpected_suffix)  # abcdef_d

x = Example.objects.get(name__randomlookup=_string)  # randomlookup is just an example
```

Then the variable x will SELECT the row with a name value of 'abcdef'. Is it possible to just use purely Django ORM with this?

**P.S.**

icontains and iregex will not solve the problem

Comment: It appears that you are using pure Django ORM, except I'm not sure what the `__lookup` is there for? `lookup` is not a standard Django queryset field lookup.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's an example.. I'm wondering if django ORM alone can handle this problem.. Or maybe you have something in mind that might solve this?

Comment: Ah ok. So your question is whether Django ORM can do queries using a dynamic lookup value? If so, the answer is yes.

Comment: Actually, I'm asking how can django orm can match values with suffix

Comment: OK, thanks for the edits. I understand. You want to match the start of a string and ignore the 'suffix'. You can use the `startswith` or `istartswith` lookup functions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#startswith.

Comment: `icontains` too. As well as `iregex`.

Comment: That's not gonna work icontains work when there is missing characters from the string that is being looked up

Comment: You're right. So effectively you want the reverse of `icontains`. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465858/django-reverse-to-contains-icontains