# Mysql like search in reverse

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I don't know if my title is telling exactly the right thing what I try to do but so on here
an example of course.

e.g.

I have a database with the fields id | animal | population ...
It's all about the animal field. I have a string like 'the animal is a fox', or 'the fox is brown'.

I would like to pass this string through a mysql query which will return me 'fox' as a match.

Thank you in advance!

Nick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: What is a reverse version of LIKE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472063/mysql-what-is-a-reverse-version-of-like)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableName
WHERE  'the animal is a fox' LIKE CONCAT('%', animal ,'%')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81ac5/3)

Comment: I have a large database that I want to do something similar with, but only if it remains indexed. If I format it like: WHERE  'the animal is a fox' LIKE CONCAT(animal ,'%') will it use the index on animal please?