# Django: Converse of `__endswith`

Tags: python, django, django-models

Django allows me to do this:

```
chair = Chair.objects.filter(name__endswith='hello')
```

But I want to do this:

```
chair = Chair.objects.filter(name__isendof='hello')
```

I know that the lookup `__isendof` doesn't exist. But I want something like this. I want it to be the converse of `__endswith`. It should find all chairs such that `'hello'.endswith(chair.name)`.

Possible in Django? ORM operations are preferable to SQL ones.

Comment: Can you give an example of what would match?

Comment: that's a weird query to need to do, are you sure there's not another way to approach your problem?

Comment: @Anentropic I am a weird person.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django ORM is not a silver bullet, there is nothing wrong in writing parts of SQL in case handling with plain ORM is difficult or impossible. This is a really good use case of [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra):

```
Entry.objects.extra(where=['"hello" LIKE CONCAT("%%", name)'])
```

Note that, since we are writing plain SQL here - it would be database backend specific anyway. This particular is mysql specific and based on this topic: [MySQL: What is a reverse version of LIKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472063/mysql-what-is-a-reverse-version-of-like). Should work for PostgreSQL too (haven't tested).

Note that you can adapt the query into a reusable [custom `Lookup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-lookups/) (introduced in Django 1.7):

- imagine you have the following model

  ```
  class MyModel(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.name
  ```
- define the `Lookup` class with an `as_sql()` method implemented:

  ```
  class ConverseEndswith(models.Lookup):
      lookup_name = 'ce'

      def as_sql(self, qn, connection):
          lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(qn, connection)
          rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(qn, connection)
          params = lhs_params + rhs_params
          return '%s LIKE CONCAT("%%%%", %s)' % (rhs, lhs), params

  models.Field.register_lookup(ConverseEndswith)
  ```
- then, here is how our custom `__ce` lookup works in [`shell`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#shell):

  ```
  >>> import django
  >>> django.setup()
  >>> from myapp.models import MyModel
  >>> for name in ['hello', 'ello', 'llo', 'test1', 'test2']:
  ...     MyModel.objects.create(name=name)

  >>> MyModel.objects.filter(name__ce='hello')
  [<MyModel: hello>, <MyModel: ello>, <MyModel: llo>]
  >>> MyModel.objects.filter(name__ce='hello').query.__str__()
  u'SELECT `myapp_mymodel`.`id`, `myapp_mymodel`.`name` FROM `myapp_mymodel` WHERE hello LIKE CONCAT("%", `myapp_mymodel`.`name`)'
  ```

---

Another option is to make the check in Python. Since the `LIKE` query would make a full scan through all of the records inside the `Entry` table, you can get them all and check one by one using Python's `endswith()`:

```
[entry for entry in Entry.objects.all() if 'hello'.endswith(entry.name)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the possibility to use Django 1.7 you can use [custom lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-lookups/). Otherwise I think you have to resort to using `.extra` or `.raw`.

Comment: That's an option, but since I don't know SQL, I have no idea how to write one.

Answer (score 0):

probably something like is as close as you are going to get ... even though its less than awesome

```
target_string = "hello"
chair = Chair.objects.filter(name__in=[target_string[-i:] for i in range(len(target_string))])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chair = Chair.objects.exclude(name__endswith='hello')
```