# MySQL search column in a specify text

Tags: mysql

I don't know how to search column in a specify text, let me give you an example:
Specify text is: "**GBX Shoe Changed**".

I have `search` table like this:

```
ID | keyword
1  |  shoe
2  |  bag
3  |  gb
4  |  hat
```

I want to get records in `search.keyword` in my specify text "GBX Shoe Changed".
The result are two records has ID 1 and 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand the question correct, what you need is the inverse of LIKE %%, this can be achieved like this:

[MySQL: What is a reverse version of LIKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472063/mysql-what-is-a-reverse-version-of-like)

```
SELECT keyword FROM search 
WHERE 'GBX Shoe Changed' LIKE
  CONCAT('%', keyword, '%')
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1784/1)**

Comment: Thanks, it's work!
I found other way for this query using Instr function
   ` SELECT keyword FROM search WHERE INSTR(GBX Shoe Changed,`save_searches.keyword`)`
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-instr-function.php

Comment: glad i could help - then you should mark it as the answer with the checkmark next to the voting arrows @Huy

Comment: @Huy nice find with the INSTR!

Comment: I'm very glad to help and find other way to to resolve an issue.